# Mounting a TV above a fireplace

Tags: fireplace, brick, television

So, we have a 65" TV that we are thinking about mounting above our fireplace.   The fireplace is made of brick and has a wooden mantel.  Is it really a bad idea to mount the TV above the fireplace?   I mean obviously I know that heat doesn't do anything good for electronics but we would, at most, have gas logs in the fireplace.  I just wasn't sure just how bad an idea it was.  Thanks.

Comment: Heat rises. The TV will see more heat than it would elsewhere. There are numerous TV shows and others that have done it, and many reports from people online saying don't do it. You wont find many saying it was a good idea because it really isn't. @MichaelKaras nailed it. I have a 22x16' living room with a 8' brick fireplace. We investigated the same idea. Wound up installing it (75") on the wall next to the fireplace with a tilt&swivel extendable mount, it can take a nice angle and covers all seat area of the room. Best idea ever. The hard part was finding a short tv table for under it.

Comment: There exists a product designed to mount a TV over a fireplace mantel.  It's designed to solve some of the problems associated with this mounting place.  Now that you know it exists, maybe you can search for it on the Internet and find it.  The web site for the product has an FAQ and the installation manuals have advice on which fireplaces are suitable and which are not.  I can't say any more or else someone will think I'm trying to sell something instead of trying to help.

Answer (score 10):

It is a bad idea. TV screens are designed to be viewed basically level from your eyes as you sit in your TV room. If you mount it above the mantel you will forever looking up to see the thing.

The heat thing is also a concern for electronics as you have mentioned. Raise the temperature some and in the best case you will age certain components and shorten the life of the TV.

You would also have to deal with the disfiguring of the brick face of the fireplace when you find that it is a less then optimal place for a TV and decide to take it down.

I fail to see why this is such a fad idea to put TV's up high on the wall.

Comment: I never understood the desire for this mounting location.  Why would someone want to strain their neck at all times.  I advise sitting on the couch and measuring your eye level.  Then, mount the TV's middle at that height or maybe 6" above that.

Comment: I agree with all of this. I have never understood why people do this. I've installed many like this for people and have always tried to talk them out of it. On a number of occasions, they'd had me come back to remove it.+

Comment: @EvilElf Its a convenient unused wall space.  Architects will design the room to make the fireplace an obvious focal point, but people also want the TV to be in the center of the room.  Layout wise, mounting a TV over a fireplace usually looks like the best option, but the height then kills the idea and makes it one of the worst locations to live with long term.

Comment: @Michael Karas - Meh, it really depends. At our last house we had the TV above the fireplace and it was fantastic. It frees up a lot of space in the room too. There was no neck strain and we had reclining seats so it was a great angle.  Plus, our TV is made such that you can angle it, so we angled it down a bit and that helped a lot.  As for the heat aging the components, we still have the same TV at the house we're in now, and the TV is 8 years old and still working fine.  We had gas logs, and a mantle, so that probably helped.

Comment: Coincidentally I just stumbled upon a subreddit that addresses your second sentence, [TV Too High](https://www.reddit.com/r/TVTooHigh/)

Comment: The heat may reduce the visibility of the screen as well. Hot air doesn't stand as still as air at room temperature. Think of the effect you see above hot asphalt in the desert sun, but less prominent.

Answer (score 5):

It may not be desired, but sometimes it's the only available wall space in the room.  FYI, we mounted our 55" above the fireplace.  But the fireplace was converted to propane at the same time.  I was able to attach it to some paneling that was used to build the fireplace surround, after appropriate reinforcing.

Here's a picture of it completed.  Note that we have not had a problem with the viewing angle.

[image]

**EDIT 1**

I'm sure having the set recessed helps with the heat.  Samsung had all sorts of info in the mounting instructions as to when being above a fireplace would be an issue.

No, I haven't noticed much heat, if any, at the surface of the TV.

**EDIT 2 - Answered question from Criggie**

The two small panels on either side of the TV were the heatilator (?) outputs.  Fireplace itself is steel/iron plate.  So there's a cavity between the steel and the brick.  Intake vent on the bottom and exhaust at the top on both sides.  Strictly convection, no forced air (fan), so never got much heat out.  The one on the right hides the shutoff valve for the propane log insert.  The one on the left I used to route the FO cable from the box (which is on one of the shelves just to the left) to the TV.

The flat panel TV doesn't put out much heat at all, as all the processing and intelligence is in the (hidden) box.

Comment: Love The Frame TV.  I think the inset your TV sits in keeps much of the rising hot air off of it.  Do you ever notice if the TV gets _any_ additional heat from the fireplace?  I have vented gas logs and things above my mantle don't seem to get very warm at all.

Comment: The bigger the ledge, the more the niche will be isolated from the heat.   I wonder about the TV's own heat output at the top.  Also, what are the two squares behind the lower two corners of the TV - look like thin dado?

Answer (score 1):

Good idea or not depends on several factors.
1) Is the sitting arrangement normally facing toward the fireplace and how close is the sitting area to the tv.  If the sitting area is close, then you would have the issues of the viewer looking up.  If the sitting area is across the room, then the angle of view to the screen is not that servere.

2) The type of chairs being used.  I have lounge type sofa that reclines, and having the tv up high is an advantage.  You should sit in the area where you plan to watch the tv and see if the height is appropriate for good viewing.

3) As others have stated, is there a heat issue that can cause problems.  Turn on the gas log, and check the temperature where you would mount the tv and see if there is a significant heat in that area.

If the viewing angle and heat is not an issue, if you do go this way, select a mounting system that allows you to tilt and rotate the screen toward the sitting area, so the screen is directed straight to the eye.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer and keep them coming.