# Mounting tv above gas fireplace?

Tags: mounting, fireplace, television, chimney

We have long wanted to mount our tv in the basement above our gas fireplace. I assume the gas fireplace insert sits inside the existing hearth with a brick chimney outside. We do not use the fireplace at all--my husband actually disconnected the gas line when we switched to a gas stove to save him some steps--but in theory, if we were to sell the house the line would get hooked back up so it could be usable.

1. Is it safe to have a decently-sized tv (50-60" I think) mounted above the mantle of the fireplace if it were up and running, in terms of heat/etc.?
2. The wall behind has no studs--we assume it's drywall with the brick fireplace directly behind. Would it compromise the fireplace/structure to drill through the drywall into the brick? I don't like drywall mounting screws in general, and I don't think there's even enough space behind the drywall for them to be an option.
3. The space is snug, but from quick measurements the tv would fit. If we had to we could change the mantel.

My husband and I have been too afraid/had too many other projects to attempt to mess with this before. We're also semi-terrified of the chimney in general due to a touch of PTSD from a bat incident shortly after we moved in. We have a mounting bracket that will fit the TV, and I can get cord covers to avoid additional labor/I don't really care about the aesthetics of the cords.

Dumb idea or not? We're avoiding purchasing a TV stand and rotating the basement layout which faces the fireplace if this doesn't work. Pic included is from our home listing since I apparently have never photographed our basement.

ETA: I have seen other similar posts, but the answers are all regarding just the potential effects of heat on the tv or the potential for neck/eye strain due to the mounting angle, and do not answer my questions regarding potential issues drilling into brick.

[image]

Comment: Or this one? [Mounting a TV above a fireplace](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/189272/mounting-a-tv-above-a-fireplace?rq=1)

Comment: I did check those, but neither was for a gas fireplace and some of the other specifics to my situation. I'm less concerned about neck/eye strain and heat than the structural integrity of the fireplace/logistics of mounting into brick.

Comment: I'd worry about fume damage, in the medium or long term.